# Is it possible to reset the ServicePointManager?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, email, network-programming

I am attempting to following the code similar to the one given at [How does System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient do its local IP binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3428052) I am using Windows 7 and .Net 4.0 on a machine with multiple IP Addresses. I have the [BindIPEndPointDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.bindipendpointdelegate.aspx) defined

```
private static IPEndPoint BindIPEndPointCallback(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount)
{
    string IPAddr = //some logic to return a different IP each time
    return new IPEndPoint(IPAddr, 0);
}
```

I then send my email using

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = SMTP_SERVER; //IP Address as string
client.Port = 25;
client.EnableSsl = false;
client.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate 
   = new System.Net.BindIPEndPoint(BindIPEndPointCallback);
client.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 0;
client.Send(msg);  //msg is of type MailMessage properly initialized/set
client = null;
```

The first time this code gets called, the delegate gets called and whatever IP address gets set, it gets used. The subsequent times this code gets called, the delegate never gets called ***i.e. the first IP Address is used subsequently.*** Is it possible to change this situation where each time the code gets called, the delegate callback is called?

I am thinking the [ServicePointManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.aspx) (which is a **static class**) caches the result of the first call to the delegate. Is it possible to reset this class? I don’t care about performance.

Thank you,
O. O.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar problem and wanted to reset **ServicePointManager** and changing certs for different outcomes of tests. The way that worked for me was to set MaxServicePointIdleTime to a low value, which would effectively reset it.

```
ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I faced in the question posted above was that all emails would be sent out using the IP of the first message. I think something *(possibly the **ServicePointManager**)* was caching the connection. While I have not found a solution to resetting the **ServicePointManager**, I realized my above attempt at setting `client = null;` does not really close the connection even if you call `GC.Collect();` soon after. The only thing I found to work was:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
//Remaining code here.... 
client.Send(msg); 
client.Dispose(); //Secret Sauce
```

Calling `client.Dispose();` after sending each message always resets the connection, so the next message can choose which IP Address it needs to go out on.

O. O.

Comment: You can wrap smtp client in a using and have it do that for you. `using(var client = new SmtpClient()) { client.Send(msg); }`