# New value not reflected in HTTP flag (Windows Application)

Tags: c#, web-services, http, caching, http-headers

I have a Windows Form Application, which gets a HTTP setting(to connect to a web-service) from the DB when the user logins.

I've found if the setting is changed, and the user re-logs, the application gets the correct value, however, upon monitoring the packets, the updated flag setting is not updated.

There are no static methods/variables, and a new object is used for each connection.

Please help.

Comment: Are you disposing of the http connection?

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working.

Didn't thought of it because it was using a SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke() call.

Comment: After a while the problem resurfaced. Further checked and it turned out to be an issue with the ServicePointManager. Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320992/is-it-possible-to-reset-the-servicepointmanager) for more details, also found that we didn't need to dispose of the connection

Should have mentioned that it was the Expect flag which was causing the issue.

Still, thanks for the initial help JCabello.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Happy to point in a random direction that sort of matched the solution whereabouts.