# How to change ip address on each requisition using a proxy?

Tags: .net, tcp, httpclient, haproxy

I have a application which uses the `WebClient` to navigate to some external pages.

On top of this application I have a `HAProxy` which makes the requests load balancing to 5 linux hosts (each one with a valid ip address).

Its working. But the problem is that HAProxy only changes the external ip when i close the application (a TCP Reset is sent by the client, so the TCP tunnel is closed).

The objective is that in each http request the application make it sends through a different ip. How can i do that?

sample code:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
 {
     using (var client = new WebClient())
     {
        //Even if i create a new WebClient and dispose, 
        //under the hood it uses the same socket, so myexternalsite01 and 02    
        //are hitted with the same ip until i close the application.
        client.DownloadString("http://myexternalsite01.com");
        client.DownloadString("http://myexternalsite02.com");
     }
  }
```

The proxy in `app.config`

```
 <system.net>
<defaultProxy>
  <proxy usesystemdefault="False" proxyaddress="http://proxy.local:3128" bypassonlocal="False" />
</defaultProxy>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320992/is-it-possible-to-reset-the-servicepointmanager

Comment: Im calling the dispose via `using` statement. But the connection keeps open.

Comment: Did you check the upvoted answer also?

Comment: It seems to work, but the socket still in TIME_WAIT state for a while.